# How does jQuery hover know how to undo changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, if I have:

```
$("tag").hover(function () {
    $("#overlay").toggle();
});
```

how does jQuery know how to un-apply the `toggle` changes when the mouse leaves? The code listed above works *as is*, but I want to know how jQuery knows what changes I've made in a callback? My question isn't how do I manually undo the changes, because I know how to do that, but rather how does jQuery know how to *automatically* undo those changes that are set in a callback function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 version in `.hover` function,

`.hover` with 2 args

1. handler for mouseenter
2. handler for mouseleave

`.hover` also has single arg version **[The version you have]**

1. handler for both mouseenter and mouseleave

   ```
     $('something').hover(function () {
        console.log('I will be called when you mouseenter and mouseleave');
     });
   ```

From docs,

> **`.hover( handlerInOut(eventObject) )Returns: jQuery`**
>
> Bind a single handler to the matched elements, to be executed when the
>   mouse pointer enters or leaves the elements.
>
> handlerInOut(eventObject) Type: Function() A function to execute when
>   the mouse pointer enters or leaves the element.

Comment: Aah, ok. I thought it was somehow monitoring the changes. I get it.

Answer (score 3):

Passing a single argument to `.hover` makes the callback run on hover in and out both - http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover2

And this is the internal implementation of toggle

```
toggle: function( state ) {
    var bool = typeof state === "boolean";

    return this.each(function() {
        if ( bool ? state : isHidden( this ) ) {
            jQuery( this ).show();
        } else {
            jQuery( this ).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

As you're not passing in any argument to `.toggle`, jQuery checks if the element is hidden using this internal function (extracted from the source code):

```
function isHidden( elem, el ) {
    // isHidden might be called from jQuery#filter function;
    // in that case, element will be second argument
    elem = el || elem;
    return jQuery.css( elem, "display" ) === "none" || !jQuery.contains( elem.ownerDocument, elem );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery hover takes 2 functions as parameters, ( both for handle in and handle out ).

http://api.jquery.com/hover/